# Implicit function theorem for discrete function

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, implicit-function-theorem

I have a function in two variabels $f(n,x)$, one of the two variabels is discrete (i.e. $n\in\mathbb{N}$).

I want to solve the function/equation $f(n,x)=0$ wrt. $x$, i.e. $x=x(n)$ using the implicit function theorem and then find the dependence of $x$ on $n$.
For a continuous variable this would be no problem with the implicit function theorem, i.e.

$$\frac{dx}{dn}=-\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}\right)^{-1}\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$

Is there any discrete analogus to this theorem? E.g.

$$ x(n)-x(n-1) = -\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{f(n,x)-f(n-1,x)}$$

The proof for the existence of the function is not a problem I can show this independently from such a theorem (but would be nice to have of course)

Comment: What does $\partial f/\partial x$ mean, with respect to $n$? Is it evaluated at $n$ or at $n+1$?  The implicit function theorem requires differentiability which does not hold for $f(n,x)$ when $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  The functions $f(1,x)$ and $f(2,x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$  may have no relationship whatsoever to each other. Take $f(1,x)=e^x-10$ and $f(2,x)=\cos(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Does this example fit your desired result?  As a general (continuously differentiable) function of $(n,x) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ this scenario holds for $$ f(x,n)=(2-n)(e^x-10)+ (n-1)\cos(x)$$

Comment: @Michael Not sure where $\partial f/\partial x$ should be evaluated, that's part of the question ;). Potentially even at both places... If it helps we can assume that $f$ is actually continuously defined in $n$, however evaluation only makes sense at integer values.

Comment: Well, my example above gives $f(x,n)$ that is already continuously differentiable over $(x,n) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, but for $n=1$ and $n=2$ it gives completely different functions of $x$.  You can define a generalized example  $f(x,n) = (2-n)g_1(x) + (n-1)g_2(x)$ for any arbitrary continuously differentiable functions $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ to see that there is essentially no relationship between $f(x,1)$ and $f(x,2)$.